# Запись в базу данных из массива?

Tags: php, mysqli

Стоит задача записать в базу данных **mysql** данные из массива.

Есть вот такие данные в виде строки:

Таролог: Астролог: Хиромант:

Записываю их в массив и експлодю по двоеточию.

```
$str = 'Таролог: Астролог: Хиромант:';
$names = explode(": ", $str);
```

Теперь задача стоит записать каждое значение из массива в базу данных:
Есть база с такими столбцами: **id, name, place, number**
А так же если в массиве повторно приходят такие же данные изменять у повторившегося **name** значение **number**.

Но есть еще одно но строка может содержать уже существующие данные и не существующие к примеру так: Таролог: Астролог: Экстрасенс:
И в данном случае нужно у тех кто существует обновить данные а не существующего добавить.

Помогите пожалуйста решить такую задачу.

Comment: Покажите пример, что вы пробовали сделать для решения задачи, и в чем возникли трудности.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. На данный момент добавляю только записи вот так:  $str = 'Таролог: Астролог: Хиромант:';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`name`, `place`, `number`) VALUES ('".implode(": ", $str)."','0','0')";
mysqli_query($db,$sql);

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам нужно вытащить записи из базы
2. Преобразовать данные в массив, как вы это уже делали
3. Если новые данные получаете от клиента, то нужно экранировать данные перед записью в базу, например [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
4. Сложить 2 массива старый и новый через функцию [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
5. Отбросить повторяющиеся элементы через функцию [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)
6. Отсортировать массив через функцию [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) в качестве сравнения строк можно использовать функцию [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp)
7. Обновить запись в базе

Comment: На каком этапе затык?

Comment: по хорошему вам бы создать таблицу profession, в ней указать все имеющиеся профессии с id и создать таблицу user_profession, где указывались бы id пользователя и id профессии, и если вам для пользователя нужно было указать другую профессию, вы бы редактировали только таблицу user_profession и больше никуда бы не лезли

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи нужно использовать запросы INSERT и UPDATE в базу данных MySQL.

Запрос INSERT используется для добавления данных в таблицу. Например, чтобы добавить данные из массива в таблицу:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (name, place, number) VALUES ";
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $sql .= "('$name', '', ''), ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ', ');
```

Запрос UPDATE используется для обновления данных в таблице. Например, чтобы обновить данные из массива в таблице:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET number = number + 1 WHERE name IN (";
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $sql .= "'$name', ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ', ');
$sql .= ")";
```